# Debugging stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: debugging, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc I'd like to debug in the SQL Server 2008 management studio.  I see a number of tutorials about doing this, but the ones I've seen don't have any input parameters going into the SP.  My SP has several, and an output parameter as well.

Could someone show me how to do debug a stored procedure with parameters in SQL 2008?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write a query that correctly invokes your SP and debug that:

```
exec MySP p1 p2 etc
```

Comment: Not forgetting to set a breakpoint in the procedure or use "step into" :)